# how to append object array to current state in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

this is my state

```js
const [dataItem, setDataItem] = useState({
    id: null,
    code: null,
    title: null,
    prent: null,
    unitId: null,
});
```

and i want append file to  dataItem state

```js
let file = [
    {
        uid: '1',
        name: items.file,
        status: 'done',
    },
];
setDataItem({ ...dataItem, file });
```

but it instead of append to dataItem , it replaced and other elements(e.g id, code, title) will be null
 dataItem state after append file

```
{
    "id": null,
    "code": null,
    "title": null,
    "prent": null,
    "unitId": null,
    "file":[{
        "uid": "1",
        "name": "u104.svg",
        "status": "done"
    }]
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output after append file to dataItem state?

Answer (score 1):

Because the state was initialized to an `object` instead of an `array`. It should be

```
const [dataItem, setDataItem] = useState([{
    id: null,
    code: null,
    title: null,
    prent: null,
    unitId: null,
}]);
```

When update `dataItem`, you have to spread array `file` too

`setDataItem({ ...dataItem, ...file });`

---

Read more => 
[Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

To append `file` keeping the previous state intact, you'll need to use functional updates.

```
let file = [
  {
    uid: '1',
    name: items.file,
    status: 'done',
  },
];
setDataItem(prevState => ({ ...prevState, file }));
```